# Writing Single summation with two variables

Tags: summation, formal-proofs

I have the following summation,

[image]

What its the mathematically correct way to write this summation using the summation symbol? Note that I will need 2 variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

$$\sum_{i=1}^{N-t}A_{t+i}(k-i)\;.$$

This can also be written

$$\sum_{i=t+1}^NA_i(k+t-i)\;.$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to write it:
$$ \sum_{j=1}^{N-t}A_{t+j}(k-j) $$